# How to convert number 1:4 into seasons character in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm currently working on a project in which I have a column called 'season'. This column contains numbers 1:4 pertaining to the 4 seasons in a year. I'm new to R and want to create a new column that has seasons characterized for each number e.g. 1 = Spring, 2 = Summer, 3 = Autumn, and 4 = Winter. Below is an image of my data frame I am working with. Any help and tips would be much appreciated.

[image: Dataframe image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the stack! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already. Please could you edit your question so that it includes reproducible data? In R, you can do this by using the `dput()` function on a small section of your data frame. Please don't include code or data as an image, for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the integer vector as an index in a string (`character`) vector.

```r
set.seed(123)
seasons <- c("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter")
idx <- sample(1:4, 10, TRUE)
idx
# [1] 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 1
seasons[idx]
# [1] "Autumn" "Autumn" "Autumn" "Summer" "Autumn" "Summer" "Summer" "Summer"
# [9] "Autumn" "Spring"
```

Comment: Here is how you could implement this: `dplyr::mutate(df, class = c("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter")[season])` or `df$class <- c("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter")[sd$season]`

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach:

```
  df$seasons <- as.factor(df$season)
  levels(df$seasons) = c("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter")
```